# Subquery for a where condition issue

Tags: mysql, node.js

I don't know how to name or word this better, and that is causing my search to be skewed.

I have this statement, which works.

```
SELECT username
     , ip 
  FROM database.users 
 WHERE ip = (SELECT ip 
               FROM database.users_chat_history 
              WHERE username = ? 
              limit 1);
```

But, I need something like this, which isn't allowed:

```
SELECT username
     , ip 
  FROM database.users 
 WHERE ip = (SELECT ip 
                  , posted_at 
               FROM database.users_chat_history 
              WHERE username = ? 
              group 
                 by posted_at desc 
              limit 1);
```

> Error: ER_OPERAND_COLUMNS: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Reason being is I need it to grab the newest/most recent row when doing that search, and with that first one, it's not doing that, which is causing issues. The second query, I only need the ip for the statement to work, but I need it to group by posted_at descending so it grabs the newest post.

EDIT:
Database sample for inner query:
[image]

Comment: You are not using aggregation function .. so why you use group by in select .?. try explain what is you goal .. eventually update your question with a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: order by posted_at desc will give you latest record

Comment: Updated with sample but someone answered it working below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should replace "group by" with ORDER BY clause. See below:

```
SELECT username, ip FROM database.users WHERE ip = (SELECT ip FROM database.users_chat_history WHERE username = ? ORDER BY posted_at desc limit 1);
```

Comment: Thank you, this answered it.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this for the subquery:

```
SELECT ip FROM database.users_chat_history WHERE username = ? ORDER BY posted_at ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Untested but should return ip only (one column), and one record only (adapt ASC/DESC) accordingly to what you are looking for

Comment: This works as well (obviously, being the same code), just isn't complete with full query, which is why I selected the other answer as the one that solved my question, just in-case someone in future searches and comes along this. Thank you for helping, I appreciate it!